# How to draw on VLC surface using delphi

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010, draw, vlc

I have Delphi [VLC](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/) bindings, and i need to do some kind of on-screen display (OSD) menu. How can i draw on a video surface from `VLC`. I know that i can use [SDL](http://www.libsdl.org/) but i wondering can `VLC` do that.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it can do that but you have to find a VLC OSD delphi wrapper or you need to implement it for delphi

this link is the header files for make OSD menu with VLC

osdmenu.html">http://www.videolan.org/developers/vlc/doc/doxygen/html/group_osdmenu.html